# Resource recommendation for fractional statistics

Tags: condensed-matter, resource-recommendations, anyons

A gentle yet comprehensive introduction to the concept of abelian and non-abelian statistics will be much appreciated.

Comment: Maybe not the simplest, but certainly clear and worth your time: from the man himself, Kitaev's "Anyons in an exactly solved model and beyond" (arXiv:cond-mat/0506438). The introduction nicely describes abelian anyons/braiding, chapter 8 (and appendix E) describes the non-abelian case.

Comment: @RubenVerresen how is that not an answer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Abelian

- According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anyon#Abelian_anyons), quasiparticles whose statistics range between Fermi-Dirac and Bose-Einstein statistics are called anyons; these particles may only exist in two dimensions. These particles obey fractional statistics, so called because they have fractional spin; see Frank Wilczek's [Quantum Mechanics of Fractional-Spin Particles](http://www.ifi.unicamp.br/%7Emtamash/f689_mecquant_i/prl49_957.pdf) where he also coins the term anyon.
- In the same vein, see Jon Magne Leinaas and Jan Myrheim's paper [On the Theory of Identical Particles](http://www.ifi.unicamp.br/%7Ecabrera/teaching/referencia.pdf) where they showed quasiparticles can indeed be observed in two dimensions.

### Non-abelian

- According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anyon#Abelian_anyons), in 1988, Jurg Frohlich showed that non-abelian statistics existed and were valid, in his paper [Statistics of Fields, the Yang-Baxter Equation, and the Theory of Knots and Links](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-1-4613-0729-7_4) (note there's a paywall there).
- Again according to wikipedia, Gregory Moore, Nicholas Read, and Xiao-Geng Wen showed non-abelian statistics can be realized in the fractional quantum Hall effect, and wrote two papers, [Non-Abelian Statistics in the Fractional Quantum Hall States](http://dao.mit.edu/%7Ewen/pub/nab.pdf) (Wen) and [Nonabelions In the Fractional Quantum Hall Effect](http://www.physics.rutgers.edu/%7Egmoore/MooreReadNonabelions.pdf) (Read and Moore; see section 2.1 in particular).

### Other/general

- [Fractional Statistics and Quantum Theory](https://books.google.com/books?id=tA23CgAAQBAJ&dq=Fractional+Statistics+and+Quantum+Theory) (book) by Avinash Khare covers, as the title indicates, anyons and their statistics. The copyright is 1997, so it won't talk much about the applications of anyons to quantum computing; however, it covers pretty much every topic related to abelian/non-abelian statistics as far as I can tell, so if you're willing to pay money (the Google Books sample is decent, but doesn't include every page, obviously) this is probably your **best bet**. If you do decide this is what you want, the [hardcover copy on Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/9810225229) is $25, so not too bad compared to a lot of technical books. *Mathematical Reviews* said

  > The overall style is clear and pedagogical, with emphasis on symmetry and simplicity.
- If you wish to read about the construction of quantum computation theory using anyons, the paper [Topological quantum computation](http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/2003-40-01/S0273-0979-02-00964-3/S0273-0979-02-00964-3.pdf) will be of use.
- A set of lectures transcribed into a paper on arXiv called [Introduction to abelian and non-abelian anyons](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1610.09260.pdf) can be found, and they appear to cover all topics of interest.
- A powerpoint for a talk on [Fractional Quantum Statistics](http://users.physik.fu-berlin.de/%7Epelster/Anyon1/hansson.pdf) also appears to cover everything of interest, though as a powerpoint it may not describe everything in complete detail.

I'll add more papers/books/resources as I find them. Hope these help!

Answer (score 5):

I'll give you what resources I have on this topic:

**General Reviews**

1. [Lecture Notes on Anyonic Defects in Condensed Matter](http://theory.fi.infn.it/SFTschool/SFT_2015/LectureNotes/Berg1-2.pdf)

   Lecture notes from a summer school in Florence. A good reference for Majorana zero modes and anyonic defects in condensed matter systems. Large amount of detail--pretty clear.
2. [Braiding with Majorana Fermions](https://www.csee.umbc.edu/~lomonaco/pubs/QITSpie2016.pdf)

   A good, simple introduction to braiding with anyons and its connection to Majorana fermions. Applications to quantum computing included.
3. [An Anyon Primer](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9209066)

   Excellent introduction to the field with problems, though it can get a little advanced in some places. Applications to the fractional quantum hall effect included.
4. [Quantiki's Introduction to Anyons](https://www.quantiki.org/wiki/anyons)

   Brief, but possibly a solid starting point. Good links and references as well.
5. [This StackExchange question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/5029/how-non-abelian-anyons-arise-in-solid-state-systems) on non-Abelian anyons in solid state physics might also be useful. [See also this StackExchange question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/61915/some-questions-about-anyons?rq=1) for some nice clarifications and links.

**Presentations**

6. [Fractional Quantum Statistics](http://users.physik.fu-berlin.de/~pelster/Anyon1/hansson.pdf)

   Great presentation on anyons and fractional statistics. Very simple and easily understood. Draws analogies and examples from simple quantum systems. An undergraduate with a background in Griffiths could understand the majority of this presentation.
7. [Fractional Statistics in Two Dimensions: Anyon There?](http://www.perimeterinstitute.ca/videos/fractional-statistics-two-dimensions-anyon-there)

   Video introducing the concept of anyons to a general audience, from the Perimeter Institute in Waterloo, Ontario. Connections to superconductors are drawn.

**Books**

8. [Fractional Statistics and Anyon Superconductivity](https://books.google.com/books/about/Fractional_Statistics_and_Anyon_Supercon.html?id=MHf9sBNPszkC)

   Good introduction to the subject by Frank Wilczek, but a bit dated. Has a nice selection of original papers on the topic.
9. [Anyons: Quantum Mechanics of Particles with Fractional Statistics](https://books.google.com/books?id=BHQKBwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=anyons&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj02qizmK3UAhXBOT4KHY3cATsQ6AEIJjAA#v=onepage&q=anyons&f=false)

   By far the best resource on this list. Alberto Lerda's book is *the* book on anyonic physics, and the best, clearest resource on the subject. Covers a wide range of subject matter, and is understandable at the advanced undergraduate level.

I hope these help. Sorry if there are some duplicates with heather's reply--I tried to list resources that I've found helpful in my own study of fractional statistics.